# TLS handshake failure

Tags: ssl, handshake, google-cloud-platform

I have an embedded IOT device connected to real time DB FireBase. However, the server cancel the TLS handshake with fatal alert 0x46 = protocol_version. I have managed to get an hex dump of the whole handshake process.

Can someone explain me why the handshake was canceled?
My device is using TLS V1.2 as firebase expected as it can be seen in the header (16 3 3).

Update:
I've noticed that the first 4 bytes in the client random are zero. They need to be a calculated in seconds from 1970AD. There is no internal Time function (like we have in WIN32 or UNIX) and I used br_x509_minimal_set_time() to set the time for the BearSSL

Thanks,

**Hexa dump:**

Client Hello (Output from my IOT device to the peer)

```
16 3 1 0 E2 1 0 0 DE 3 3 0 0 0 0 E6 1F 4 48 79 54 47 D3 D7 CB FF C8 69 43 C8 66 7 ED DE 9C AF 96 8C F2 E 97 AD A6 0 0 5A CC A9 CC A8 C0 2B C0 2F C0 2C C0 30 C0 AC C0 AD C0 AE C0 AF C0 23 C0 27 C0 24 C0 28 C0 9 C0 13 C0 A C0 14 C0 2D C0 31 C0 2E C0 32 C0 25 C0 29 C0 26 C0 2A C0 4 C0 E C0 5 C0 F 0 9C 0 9D C0 9C C0 9D C0 A0 C0 A1 0 3C 0 3D 0 2F 0 35 C0 8 C0 12 C0 3 C0 D 0 A 1 0 0 5B FF 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 24 0 22 0 0 1F 69 72 6F 6E 6D 61 78 73 6F 73 62 75 74 74 6F 6E 2E 66 69 72 65 62 61 73 65 69 6F 2E 63 6F 6D 0 D 0 16 0 14 4 3 3 3 5 3 6 3 2 3 4 1 3 1 5 1 6 1 2 1 0 A 0 A 0 8 0 17 0 18 0 19 0 1D 0 B 0 2 1 0
```

Server hello (Input from the peer)

```
16 3 3 0 5B 2 0 0 57 3 3 5F DD D0 79 2B C1 D 5C 7 F3 C1 95 A2 D9 36 8C C7 4B DA 9F A2 22 D4 31 CF C9 C1 AB 86 5D CC A2 20 E3 4A 89 12 38 A0 31 D 9A 0 76 D0 E9 AE F2 F 9D 56 4C 36 4E A0 39 A5 AD D1 39 6B 3 33 8F 88 CC A8 0 0 F 0 0 0 0 FF 1 0 1 0 0 B 0 2 1 0
```

Certificate (Input)

```
16 3 3 9 FB B 0 9 F7 0 9 F4 0 5 A0 30 82 5 9C 30 82 4 84 A0 3 2 1 2 2 11 0 F0 CB F2 8F DF 22 56 9C 8 0 0 0 0 2F EE 22 30 D 6 9 2A 86 48 86 F7 D 1 1 B 5 0 30 42 31 B 30 9 6 3 55 4 6 13 2 55 53 31 1E 30 1C 6 3 55 4 A 13 15 47 6F 6F 67 6C 65 20 54 72 75 73 74 20 53 65 72 76 69 63 65 73 31 13 30 11 6 3 55 4 3 13 A 47 54 53 20 43 41 20 31 4F 31 30 1E 17 D 32 30 30 32 32 30 31 39 33 36 30 36 5A 17 D 32 31 30 32 31 38 31 39 33 36 30 36 5A 30 68 31 B 30 9 6 3 55 4 6 13 2 55 53 31 13 30 11 6 3 55 4 8 13 A 43 61 6C 69 66 6F 72 6E 69 61 31 16 30 14 6 3 55 4 7 13 D 4D 6F 75 6E 74 61 69 6E 20 56 69 65 77 31 13 30 11 6 3 55 4 A 13 A 47 6F 6F 67 6C 65 20 4C 4C 43 31 17 30 15 6 3 55 4 3 13 E 66 69 72 65 62 61 73 65 69 6F 2E 63 6F 6D 30 82 1 22 30 D 6 9 2A 86 48 86 F7 D 1 1 1 5 0 3 82 1 F 0 30 82 1 A 2 82 1 1 0 DF 51 84 12 1 76 47 89 16 CC BC E2 2E F5 27 E4 D2 44 2D 3A F7 D8 F2 9F F2 44 95 F4 A9 57 F4 D8 B2 66 EB 83 36 1D B5 94 99 A0 21 3E 17 CE 64 5A 61 EB 7F 2F F0 5C BD 44 5A 3 B9 E1 74 A7 BD 28 F0 51 9E 59 CE 98 5B 66 E3 E 1 22 50 A3 AA 9E 57 35 D0 AC 11 F6 2D 58 A7 13 C4 49 FA 3C 89 65 60 6E F9 E8 10 95 71 37 4A FA 11 F 4F 1B FA 7D 8C DB EC 2F 4A D4 EE 2A 86 A5 2F 11 44 85 E3 6B 6E 94 A9 BE 5A C6 FD 30 82 EE BB 2B 3C 69 BD 2B 3A E7 83 15 C1 3C B6 AB AB 62 DC 13 F8 9B 51 41 DF 21 C6 70 BA 4D BD F0 77 60 16 34 56 F CF B5 CF 29 24 46 D 21 6 E6 37 B 4D AE 8E C8 8D 2E 43 7E 81 20 50 2C 70 F6 55 12 2C 7B 1 62 1B B3 2F 66 C1 1D 61 8C 56 13 C B0 90 3A A 2 0 4C 22 1B 33 14 35 DF DD 41 C3 1A 6A 7D EA 3E EC 73 3E 4F FB 5A 46 40 98 10 35 4D 8A 73 AB 3B 63 E9 2 3 1 0 1 A3 82 2 65 30 82 2 61 30 E 6 3 55 1D F 1 1 FF 4 4 3 2 5 A0 30 13 6 3 55 1D 25 4 C 30 A 6 8 2B 6 1 5 5 7 3 1 30 C 6 3 55 1D 13 1 1 FF 4 2 30 0 30 1D 6 3 55 1D E 4 16 4 14 DA 22 8D DC A2 42 AB 7B 5 4A 6E F6 D3 60 3E D2 58 2C 13 42 30 1F 6 3 55 1D 23 4 18 30 16 80 14 98 D1 F8 6E 10 EB CF 9B EC 60 9F 18 90 1B A0 EB 7D 9 FD 2B 30 64 6 8 2B 6 1 5 5 7 1 1 4 58 30 56 30 27 6 8 2B 6 1 5 5 7 30 1 86 1B 68 74 74 70 3A 2F 2F 6F 63 73 70 2E 70 6B 69 2E 67 6F 6F 67 2F 67 74 73 31 6F 31 30 2B 6 8 2B 6 1 5 5 7 30 2 86 1F 68 74 74 70 3A 2F 2F 70 6B 69 2E 67 6F 6F 67 2F 67 73 72 32 2F 47 54 53 31 4F 31 2E 63 72 74 30 2B 6 3 55 1D 11 4 24 30 22 82 E 66 69 72 65 62 61 73 65 69 6F 2E 63 6F 6D 82 10 2A 2E 66 69 72 65 62 61 73 65 69 6F 2E 63 6F 6D 30 21 6 3 55 1D 20 4 1A 30 18 30 8 6 6 67 81 C 1 2 2 30 C 6 A 2B 6 1 4 1 D6 79 2 5 3 30 2F 6 3 55 1D 1F 4 28 30 26 30 24 A0 22 A0 20 86 1E 68 74 74 70 3A 2F 2F 63 72 6C 2E 70 6B 69 2E 67 6F 6F 67 2F 47 54 53 31 4F 31 2E 63 72 6C 30 82 1 3 6 A 2B 6 1 4 1 D6 79 2 4 2 4 81 F4 4 81 F1 0 EF 0 75 0 F6 5C 94 2F D1 77 30 22 14 54 18 8 30 94 56 8E E3 4D 13 19 33 BF DF C 2F 20 B CC 4E F1 64 E3 0 0 1 70 64 50 91 CE 0 0 4 3 0 46 30 44 2 20 2 A0 A AA 37 B4 C9 31 3F E9 41 83 35 63 EF D3 EE 45 E2 D9 CE E4 E E8 A4 1 A2 FC 9C 91 51 F1 2 20 60 2B 2 EB 2E 4D 49 C6 E0 D2 87 33 B0 BA EF 4D 79 A3 BE BA A9 17 92 16 6A 26 4F FC 0 50 5C 51 0 76 0 44 94 65 2E B0 EE CE AF C4 40 7 D8 A8 FE 28 C0 DA E6 82 BE D8 CB 31 B5 3F D3 33 96 B5 B6 81 A8 0 0 1 70 64 50 92 27 0 0 4 3 0 47 30 45 2 20 4D 5 84 E0 5 CA A6 14 51 9D C6 3E 5D 84 D6 A6 84 80 80 C B7 1C DD 46 E2 73 61 40 C1 E3 90 D1 2 21 0 CD 4C B6 65 EE 99 5F B1 BE 1D D6 45 83 C F4 33 AB 5C 84 7B EA AC D0 61 C7 48 F2 CE 44 9C D7 64 30 D 6 9 2A 86 48 86 F7 D 1 1 B 5 0 3 82 1 1 0 93 6B AB 76 2D D2 BB 81 1B 91 28 49 78 BD 8F EB 36 13 E6 6C F2 E4 92 26 68 9 E6 5 8E CB D7 62 6A 3F 1E 97 8C 47 57 AD 46 2E 16 A5 78 27 A3 49 46 F1 AE 76 60 83 C1 BB 75 65 18 9B C7 B5 EA D7 F9 24 4D 90 FC B9 57 ED C1 73 6A 88 EA 41 AB FC C D3 96 39 8E 56 CA A3 A3 45 E9 D6 70 AD 1C E5 15 15 6 74 1E B9 C6 D 51 A AE 31 6F 9 3F 50 69 59 7 43 FF 6E 6B ED 1 A3 1C FD 4E 21 9D 5 EB B8 74 8D A7 43 DB B2 C5 2 79 EB A 8D 1A B9 8 39 E FA 6D 4B 5 92 A6 15 93 FE 87 81 C9 80 AC 56 1 1A D4 7 85 F1 70 FC 76 57 7D EF 7E 78 3D C5 E9 FE F D5 2E D3 B8 27 6 B4 85 58 B2 F5 3F 8B 31 DF F6 AA 5B B AB 3 9C A B2 FB C2 90 AF FB 22 A1 7B 8F 6C 64 F8 C7 B4 85 6A 17 2B 91 CC CB 7 75 7D FE F5 76 C8 D2 9E 8E C1 37 D9 E7 73 CA 3C 7A 4 59 EA 59 C8 93 8B CB 7A 78 51 C0 0 4 4E 30 82 4 4A 30 82 3 32 A0 3 2 1 2 2 D 1 E3 B4 9A A1 8D 8A A9 81 25 69 50 B8 30 D 6 9 2A 86 48 86 F7 D 1 1 B 5 0 30 4C 31 20 30 1E 6 3 55 4 B 13 17 47 6C 6F 62 61 6C 53 69 67 6E 20 52 6F 6F 74 20 43 41 20 2D 20 52 32 31 13 30 11 6 3 55 4 A 13 A 47 6C 6F 62 61 6C 53 69 67 6E 31 13 30 11 6 3 55 4 3 13 A 47 6C 6F 62 61 6C 53 69 67 6E 30 1E 17 D 31 37 30 36 31 35 30 30 30 30 34 32 5A 17 D 32 31 31 32 31 35 30 30 30 30 34 32 5A 30 42 31 B 30 9 6 3 55 4 6 13 2 55 53 31 1E 30 1C 6 3 55 4 A 13 15 47 6F 6F 67 6C 65 20 54 72 75 73 74 20 53 65 72 76 69 63 65 73 31 13 30 11 6 3 55 4 3 13 A 47 54 53 20 43 41 20 31 4F 31 30 82 1 22 30 D 6 9 2A 86 48 86 F7 D 1 1 1 5 0 3 82 1 F 0 30 82 1 A 2 82 1 1 0 D0 18 CF 45 D4 8B CD D3 9C E4 40 EF 7E B4 DD 69 21 1B C9 CF 3C 8E 4C 75 B9 F 31 19 84 3D 9E 3C 29 EF 50 D 10 93 6F 5 80 80 9F 2A A0 BD 12 4B 2 E1 3D 9F 58 16 24 FE 30 9F B 74 77 55 93 1D 4B F7 4D E1 92 82 10 F6 51 AC C C3 B2 22 94 F 34 6B 98 10 49 E7 B 9D 83 39 DD 20 C6 1C 2D EF D1 18 61 65 E7 23 83 20 A8 23 12 FF D2 24 7F D4 2F E7 44 6A 5B 4D D7 50 66 B0 AF 9E 42 63 5 FB E0 1C C4 63 61 AF 9F 6A 33 FF 62 97 BD 48 D9 D3 7C 14 67 DC 75 DC 2E 69 E8 F8 6D 78 69 D0 B7 10 5 B8 F1 31 C2 3B 24 FD 1A 33 74 F8 23 E0 EC 6B 19 8A 16 C6 E3 CD A4 CD B DB B3 A4 59 60 38 88 3B AD 1D B9 C6 8C A7 53 1B FC BC D9 A4 AB BC DD 3C 61 D7 93 15 98 EE 81 BD 8F E2 64 47 20 40 6 4E D7 AC 97 E8 B9 C0 59 12 A1 49 25 23 E4 ED 70 34 2C A5 B4 63 7C F9 A3 3D 83 D1 CD 6D 24 AC 7 2 3 1 0 1 A3 82 1 33 30 82 1 2F 30 E 6 3 55 1D F 1 1 FF 4 4 3 2 1 86 30 1D 6 3 55 1D 25 4 16 30 14 6 8 2B 6 1 5 5 7 3 1 6 8 2B 6 1 5 5 7 3 2 30 12 6 3 55 1D 13 1 1 FF 4 8 30 6 1 1 FF 2 1 0 30 1D 6 3 55 1D E 4 16 4 14 98 D1 F8 6E 10 EB CF 9B EC 60 9F 18 90 1B A0 EB 7D 9 FD 2B 30 1F 6 3 55 1D 23 4 18 30 16 80 14 9B E2 7 57 67 1C 1E C0 6A 6 DE 59 B4 9A 2D DF DC 19 86 2E 30 35 6 8 2B 6 1 5 5 7 1 1 4 29 30 27 30 25 6 8 2B 6 1 5 5 7 30 1 86 19 68 74 74 70 3A 2F 2F 6F 63 73 70 2E 70 6B 69 2E 67 6F 6F 67 2F 67 73 72 32 30 32 6 3 55 1D 1F 4 2B 30 29 30 27 A0 25 A0 23 86 21 68 74 74 70 3A 2F 2F 63 72 6C 2E 70 6B 69 2E 67 6F 6F 67 2F 67 73 72 32 2F 67 73 72 32 2E 63 72 6C 30 3F 6 3 55 1D 20 4 38 30 36 30 34 6 6 67 81 C 1 2 2 30 2A 30 28 6 8 2B 6 1 5 5 7 2 1 16 1C 68 74 74 70 73 3A 2F 2F 70 6B 69 2E 67 6F 6F 67 2F 72 65 70 6F 73 69 74 6F 72 79 2F 30 D 6 9 2A 86 48 86 F7 D 1 1 B 5 0 3 82 1 1 0 1A 80 3E 36 79 FB F3 2E A9 46 37 7D 5E 54 16 35 AE C7 4E 8 99 FE BD D1 34 69 26 52 66 7 3D A BA 49 CB 62 F4 F1 1A 8E FC 11 4F 68 96 4C 74 2B D3 67 DE B2 A3 AA 5 8D 84 4D 4C 20 65 F A5 96 DA D 16 F8 6C 3B DB 6F 4 23 88 6B 3A 6C C1 60 BD 68 9F 71 8E EE 2D 58 34 7 F0 D5 54 E9 86 59 FD 7B 5E D 21 94 F5 8C C9 A8 F8 D8 F2 AD CC F 1A F3 9A A7 A9 4 27 F9 A3 C9 B0 FF 2 78 6B 61 BA C7 35 2B E8 56 FA 4F C3 1C C ED B6 3C B4 4B EA ED CC E1 3C EC DC D 8C D6 3E 9B CA 42 58 8B CC 16 21 17 40 BC A2 D6 66 EF DA C4 15 5B CD 89 AA 9B 9 26 E7 32 D2 D 6E 67 20 2 5B 10 B0 90 9 9C C 1F 9E AD D8 3B EA A1 FC 6C E8 10 5C 8 52 19 51 2A 71 BB AC 7A B5 DD 15 ED 2B C9 8 2A 2C 8A B4 A6 21 AB 63 FF D7 52 49 50 D0 89 B7 AD F2 AF FB 50 AE 2F E1 95 D F3 46 AD 9D 9C F5 CA
```

Server key exchange (Input)

```
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
```

Server hello done (Input)

```
16 3 3 0 4 E 0 0 0
```

Client key exchange (Output)

```
16 3 3 0 25 10 0 0 21 20 4B EA B1 D1 7F 14 56 5D 76 1A 6B 56 B6 93 8B 76 3D EA E5 D2 95 2C C3 1 45 B5 5D F2 4F FF 91 75
```

Client change cipher spec (Output)

```
14 3 3 0 1 1
```

Client handshake finish (Output)

```
16 3 3 0 20 C4 46 D6 2C 6F A9 E9 E8 E4 BE 7B DA 5F 3E 7F 11 D6 83 31 EA 71 D7 4F CF 5E 62 36 5A F 6 AC 7F
```

Server fatal alert (Input)

```
15 3 3 0 2 2 46
```

Comment: FYI '16 03 03' no longer unambiguously means TLS1.2; TLS1.3 reuses that header value and determines the actual protocol differently. However your device _and_ the server are in fact using 1.2 not 1.3, and (I concur) rejecting your _second_ flight with  alert 0x46 makes no sense. FWIW I can connect to that server using OpenSSL 1.1.0 commandline, which gets TLS1.2 ECDHE-CHACHA20-POLY1305 just as you (initially) did. If you can reroute or intercept the device's handshake with your own server, it could give you a 'second opinion', and if there is something wrong, more detail.

Comment: Thank you for your reply dave_thompson. You mean trying to handshake to a different web server?

Comment: To a different server, yes, and one you control or at least have access to so that you can see, if it thinks there is a problem, the complete and correct details of that problem, rather than simply the alert code, which is limited at best and in this case apparently wrong.

Comment: The Client hello handshake is specifying version 3,1 (TLS 1.0). This means the highest version the client supports. IMHO your problem is a buggy client written back in the day (2000 decade) when setting this value to anything  greater than TLS 1.0 caused servers to fail. Can you configure the minimum TLS version? I am not sure why you are seeing 3,3 (TLS 1.2) messages but the final abort is most likely caused by the Client Hello and may be a delayed reaction due to Google Front Ends (GFEs).

Comment: I've made a pcap out of the hexdump for easier analysis - [test.pcap](https://filebin.ca/5lU4djdA9XAe/test.pcap). @JohnHanley: it can be clearly seen that the ClientHello is using TLS 1.2 in this pcap. Note that the record layer protocol is often TLS 1.0 with ClientHello but in the ClientHello itself the supported protocol is given as TLS 1.2 - and this is the case here too. One can also see that the future messages in the handshake have TLS 1.2 as record layer protocol.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich - I will defer to you as the TLS expert. I see the TLS 1.2 messages. However, that may be a side effect of the GFE (TLS proxying/load balancing). The TLS 1.0 spec uses the version in bytes 1&2 and not bytes 9&10. I hand decoded the hex messages and could not find anything wrong. The negotiation is fine, yet still the protocol_version abort happens. I also checked to see if his Firebase endpoint (based on the Client Hello Server Name) supports TLS 1.0 and it does. So this is a mystery. I will look at the PCAP to see if anything stands out.

Comment: Thank you all for your help and responses. Well, if the firebase support TLS1.0 then I will limit my IOT ESP8266 to TLS1.1 maximum version (instead tls1.2) and also work with weaker cipher suite (for example, I will exclude all ECDH algo' becasue they might be too hard for the ESP). I will update...

Comment: @user4432877: What the server currently supports see [this SSLLabs report](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=ironmaxsosbutton.firebaseio.com). While it does support TLS 1.0 and RSA key exchange (instead of ECDH) currently, don't count on it that it will support this in the future too, since these protocols and ciphers are considered obsolete and discouraged.

Comment: I tried to send TLS client hello with TLS version support from TLS1.0 to TLS1.1 and support cipher suite:

 BR_TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256,  

 BR_TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256,  

 BR_TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,

 BR_TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, 
And just got from the server a fatal alert  unexpected_message(10),
Is this because I choose wrong cipher suite with TLS 1.1?

Comment: @user4432877: I have still no idea what the problem is. Based on the ciphers you are using BearSSL. I've tried to use BearSSL against this server too and got the same ClientHello, ServerHello etc, i.e. of course different random and key but same ciphers offered, same cipher negotiated, same protocol version, same curve etc - only it succeeded for me. Could you do some real packet capture so that one also can see the timing of the operations?

Comment: @SteffenUllrich - You mean sniff the network? Well it not easy because it is LTE communication. 
I read here https://www.esp8266.com/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=7944 that someone sniff the ESP8266 and saw that the TLS version was 1.1
I really think that my solution will be to downgrade the TLS from 1.2 to 1.1 using the BearSSL library of course

Comment: @DDonkey: The post you cite is 4 years old and  basically claims that there is no TLS 1.2 support announced in the ClientHello. But TLS 1.2 in the ClientHello can be clearly seen in your hexdump, so this post does not apply to you.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich - Is there any time constraint during the TLS handshake? such as the delay since TCP connection establish to the first packet send?

Comment: @DDonkey: There are no such constraints in TLS itself, which does not mean that some specific implementation has these constraints. But just to be sure - did you check that TLS works in general with various other sites and that the only site failing is this specific one?

Comment: Yes, I checked with another web server and also failed

Comment: @DDonkey: In this case please setup a server you control yourself and check the log files there and also do a packet capture. Maybe what you are seeing as intended traffic at the client side is not what actually shows up as traffic at the server side. Another test would be to check if this happens only with LTE or if it happens also with WiFi.

Comment: "The TLS 1.2 spec says that the first 4 bytes should be the current time in seconds-since-1970 " .
So, could it be that I get the alert because in my case the first four bytes of the client_random are zero? they need to be gmt_unix_time according to RFC 5246

Comment: @DDonkey - I am pretty sure setting the first four bytes to the current time is no longer recommended. This is to prevent `fingerprinting`. Review to section 1.2 https://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-mathewson-no-gmtunixtime-00 In any event, the first four bytes are part of the random number. In the old days this was to help with randomness, which is not longer necessary today as we have good  random number generators.

Comment: @DDonkey: Interesting observation. But I've also tried with BearSSL and it shows exactly the same behavior in my packet capture - only that the TLS handshake succeeds. So this is likely not the case.